# PDF comparison to test one package

Tags: packages-testing

Do any of you use PDFs to test the good outputs of their packages?

I plan to do the following.

1. Build by hand examples that I indicate to be correct: TEX + PDF files.
2. Each time I update my source code, I recompile the TEX files of the first step to compare their PDFs to those marked as correct.

Do you do this? Is there an existing script that already does this?

Comment: `l3build` can do this, although typically testing using the `.log` is better. I think we need more detail to provide a solid answer

Comment: I need to check that no regression has been done in the output of, for example, tables of variation, or probabilistic trees... This is for visual outputs.

Comment: it is much more reliable to diff the log, add `\showoutput` so the log has a symbolic representation of the output. l3build will automate normalising away paths and times. This is how the latex test suite has worked for over 30 years

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there some demos, or tutorials showing how to think like a (La)TeX tester?

Comment: `texdoc l3build` or look at the test files in any of the latex3 or ho-tex github repositories

Comment: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-3/tb114wright.pdf or look at https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx for an example using `l3build` for a smaller stand-alone package

Comment: Thanks for the article, and the small repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be automated with l3build

with a directory layout containing

```
build.lua
pkg.sty
testfiles/test1.lvt
```

build.lua

```
module = "pkg"

sourcefiles={"*.sty"}
```

pkg.sty

```
\ProvidesPackage{pkg}[2022-11-19 l3build example package]

\def\foo{abc}
```

testfiles/test1.lvt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pkg}
\input{regression-test}

\begin{document}
\START

\TEST{basic expansion}{\show\foo}

\showoutput

abc \foo

\foo

\end{document}
```

You can automate running the test.

`build.lua` sets up the package,  I need to specify the `.sty` is source here as normally it assumes .sty are generated from `.dtx` sources.

The test file is a latex document, but conventionally given `.lvt` extension. You can test in various ways, here I use `\show` but also `\showoutput` which shows a symbolic representation of the pdf output.

Then

`l3build save test1`

will run latex and save a normalised test result log file as `test1.tlg`  Assuming this looks good this would normally be checked in to source control.

`l3build check`

will then run all tests

```
$ l3build check
Running checks on
  test1 (1/1)
          --> failed


  Check failed with difference files
  - ./build/test/test1.luatex.diff
  - ./build/test/test1.xetex.diff
```

as luatex uses latin modern opentype and our saved result showoutput is using computer modern, so save engine specific reference results:

```
cp ./build/test/test1.luatex.log testfiles/test1.luatex.tlg
cp ./build/test/test1.xetex.log testfiles/test1.xetex.tlg
```

Then check again:

```
$ l3build check
Running checks on
  test1 (1/1)

  All checks passed
```

Now if we make a change to the package

```
\ProvidesPackage{pkg}[2022-11-19 l3build example package]

\def\foo{
% egreg left a space
abc}
```

and run check:

```
$ l3build check
Running checks on
  test1 (1/1)
          --> failed


  Check failed with difference files
  - ./build/test/test1.luatex.diff
  - ./build/test/test1.pdftex.diff
  - ./build/test/test1.xetex.diff
```

Then you need to check the diffs and revert the change, or update the tlg files.

Comment: Great. I like that kind of automation. Thanks for this big small example! Hoping that `egreg` will not see your example. :-)

Comment: I would like `l3build save test1` to open, if it exists, the PDF `build/test/test1.pdf`. Is this a feature of `l3build`? If not, is there a simple way to hook the `save` function in the `build.lua` file to do this?

Comment: @projetmbc I think you would need to modfy the save function in l3build-check.lua, better ask a new question or feature request at github.

Comment: That's done : https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues/279 .

Comment: @projetmbc I guessed that was you:-)